# XSD to couple values of two XML elements?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

My program can return 2 XMLs like:

```
<RESPONSE>
    <ERROR_ID>1</ERROR_ID>
    <ERROR_MESSAGE>Parse error</ERROR_MESSAGE>
</RESPONSE>

<RESPONSE>
    <ERROR_ID>2</ERROR_ID>
    <ERROR_MESSAGE>Unexpected attribute</ERROR_MESSAGE>
</RESPONSE>
```

I try write some XSD file to validate if they are ok. Here what I end up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="RESPONSE" type="Response"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="Response">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="ERROR_ID" type="ErrorId"/>
            <xsd:element name="ERROR_MESSAGE" type="ErrorMessage"/>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="ErrorId">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:positiveInteger">
            <xsd:enumeration value="1"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="2"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="ErrorMessage">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="Parse error"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="Unexpected attribute"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```

It validates fine but I'm thinking if can I link up error id with error message to not let pass validation file where error id=2 will go with message from error with id=1:

```
<RESPONSE>
    <ERROR_ID>2</ERROR_ID>
    <ERROR_MESSAGE>Parse error</ERROR_MESSAGE>
</RESPONSE>
```

There is a good way to do this? My program returns of course a lot more error ids and message.

Maybe a better question is if I should even expect such a validation from XSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XSD 1.0** cannot constrain the value of one element based upon the value of another element.

**XSD 1.1** could do so using `xsd:assert`, however you should reconsider your design...

**Alternative design suggestions:**

1. Don't check the `ERROR_ID`-`ERROR_MESSAGE` pairing in XSD.
2. Concatenate the error id with the error message:

   ```
   <Error>1. Parse error</Error>
   ```
3. Used fixed attributes against more specific error element names:

   ```
   <ParseError id="1" message="Parse error"/>
   <UnexpectedAttributeError id="2" message="Unexpected attribute"/>
   ```

None of these alternative designs require XSD 1.1.